# How to remove duplicates from an sstate cache?

Tags: yocto

I want to remove duplicates from an sstate cache in yocto because the folder is too big.
How can I do that?

Answer (score 0):

Run sstate-cache-management.sh to remove duplicates from an sstate cache.

```
$ cd buildDir/layers/oe-core/scripts;
$ ./sstate-cache-management.sh --yes --remove-duplicated --cache-dir=sstateDir
```